# Gnuplot, how to invert x with y while plotting file data?

Tags: graphics, plot, coordinates, gnuplot

I have a 'data.txt' file containing two columns and N rows, corresponding to N points, e.g.

```
0.2 0.3
0.4 0.6
0.1 0.7
0.9 0.6
```

If I use `Gnuplot` to plot data from this file, using the command

```
plot "datafile.txt" with lp
```

it plots every point in the default form (X, Y), that is `Gnuplot` interprets the first column as all the X values, and the second column as all the Y values.

I would like to invert the meaning of X and Y. I would like to set `Gnuplot` this command: "Take the first column as Y, and the second column as X"
And so I would like `Gnuplot` to take all the data from file like (Y,X) and plot them as (X,Y).

How could I do this?

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gnuplot> plot "./data.txt" using 2:1 with lp
```

"using" will allow you to select arbitrary columns from your data.